# Awkward python class behaviour?

Tags: python

I have the following simple code:

```
class Node:
    pass

def make_node(value):
    n = Node
    n.value = value
    return n

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list = range(100)
    random.shuffle(list)
    nodes = []
    for i in range(len(list)):
        nodes.append(make_node(list[i]))

    for n in nodes:
        print n.value
```

Upon printing the value at each of the nodes, they are all identical.  It seems that each "new node" i built simply overwrites the value of all of the previous ones.  Why are these not being set completely separately, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to call the `Node` constructor:

```
    n = Node()
```

Otherwise, the assignment to `n.value` is the same as assigning to `Node.value`, which sets an attribute of the *class*, not the *object* you wanted to create. By returning the `Node` class object itself, your `nodes` list contains a bunch of references to the same `Node` class object.

Comment: You may be able to infer that you're not the only one who's made this mistake. :)